# Updating roster by one day using case statement

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

In MySQL Workbench, I am trying to increment a column by one day for the next week they work.. i.e. if `employee` works on Monday this week, next week he must work Tuesday, then following week on Wednesday...and so on.

I have been trying to achieve this by using a `case` stored procedure, but have had no luck (just returns `null` for all tuples when execute. Should I be using a `cursor` instead to loop through table?

This is what I have so far:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `UpdateRoster`(inout workShift int(4))
BEGIN
        SELECT workShift
        FROM roster;

        CASE 

        WHEN workShift = Mon THEN SET workShift = Tue;
        WHEN workShift = Tue THEN SET workShift = Wed;
        WHEN workShift = Wed THEN SET workShift = Thur;
        WHEN workShift = Thur THEN SET workShift = Fri;
        WHEN workShift = Fri THEN SET workShift = Sat;
        WHEN workShift = Sat THEN SET workShift = Sun;
        WHEN workShift = Sun THEN SET workShift = Mon;

        END CASE;        
END
```

Table **before** call to update:

`roster
 employee  branch  workShift
   0001      01       Mon
   0001      01       Tues
   0001      01       Thurs
   0001      01       Sat`

Table **after** call to update:

`roster
 employee  branch  workShift
   0001      01       Tues
   0001      01       Wed
   0001      01       Fri
   0001      01       Sun`

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: That's actually a case _statement_, not a case _expression_. (A case expression has a return value, a case statement is for conditional execution of code.)

Comment: @jarlh thanks, fixed up.

Comment: Don't you need an _inout_ parameter?

Comment: @jarlh yes my code does now, sorry didn't noticed when put code in.

Comment: Why not doing this arithmetically, instead of by CASE statements, and then converting the result to a weekday with something like DATENAME(DW, workshift)?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff added table before call and after call (expected result)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but you would seem to want an `update`:

```
 UPDATE roster r
      SET workShift = (CASE WHEN workShift = 'Mon' THEN 'Tue'
                            WHEN workShift = 'Tue' THEN 'Wed'
                            WHEN workShift = 'Wed' THEN 'Thur'
                            WHEN workShift = 'Thur' THEN 'Fri'
                            WHEN workShift = 'Fri' THEN 'Sat'
                            WHEN workShift = 'Sat' THEN 'Sun'
                            WHEN workShift = 'Sun' THEN 'Mon'
                       END);
```

This is a guess of what you might want.  I should note that there are other ways to accomplish this logic as well.